# Responsive input size grows when inside input-prepend with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When I resize this fiddle, the input box gets larger when I shrink the screen. Unfortunately on the iPhone, it's going off the screen in my app.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6Bhx/5/embedded/result/ and here is the code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">
    <table width="500">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-prepend">
                   <span class="add-on">$</span>
                   <input type="text" name="fee" value="" class="span6" />

                </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="span6">Test</div>
</div>
```

Also yes, I realize I am using tables. I am not doing this to format data, it is actually being used for tabular data which happens to have input boxes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the table width @ 500px will likely cause a problem as the viewpoint shrinks to mobile size. Try removing the table width and see what happens.

**Update**

I can't picture exactly how you want the final page and table to look, but here are a few additional points you could check.

Regarding the iPhone display issue, make sure that in the head of your page you have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I think that specifying a table width of 100% will be invalid HTML5. I doubt that this is the source of your problem, but try something like this in your CSS:

```
.span6 table{
width:100%;
}
```

I can see that having the form with an input prepend inside a table is going to be a challenge. If there is no way around this, you have a nesting problem at the moment -- the input.span6 is actually nested inside the another span6 column.

In general, the HTML for a nested grid with fluid rows is:

```
<div class="row-fluid">  
<div class="span6">  

  <div class="row-fluid"> <!-- start nested grid -->
  <div class="span12">
  <!-- Form and table details here -->
  </div> <!-- end nested span -->
  </div> <!-- end nested row -->  

</div> <!-- end span6 -->  

<div class="span6">  
  test  
</div>
</div>
```

See the fluid nesting section on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem for full details.

Good luck!

Comment: In my actual program I set it to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Either set a width on slider :

```
<input style="width:125px;" type="text" name="fee" value="" class="span6" />
```

or use css

```
.span6 { width: 125px; }
```

The reason is the table is changing row widths on page resize

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use  `table width="100%"`  .

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on">$</span>

                    <input type="text" name="fee" value="" class="span6"
                    />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div span="6">Test</div>
</div>
```